# why am I getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLineCount' of undefined" on a beforeSubmit UE script triggered on a Journal Entry record

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am unsure how to troubleshoot or what this error means in NetSuites SuiteScript. There I am getting after I hit save on a journal entry is.:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLineCount' of undefined [at Object.beforeSubmit (/SuiteScripts/Set Line Employee ADP ID.js:15:30)]"

I believe the error is with my getLineCount() function on line 15.

Functional Scenario: I am writing a script to populate a custom column field on a Journal entry line from a field on the customer record that is selected in the native entity field on the Journal Entry line.

Context: my script is triggering before submit on create or update of a Journal Entry

Here is my script:

```
define (['N/record','N/runtime','N/search','N/log'],(rec,runtime,search,log)=> {
    // Logic Of the before submit actions of the script: 
    function beforeSubmit(context){

        //Find how many lines are in this JE
        let jeLineNums = context.rec.getLineCount({
            sublistId:'line'
        });

        //log the JE line numbers as a test
        log.debug({
            title: 'JE lines',
            details: jeLineNums
        });

        // Loop through every line in the Journal Entry
        for (let i = 0; i < jeLineNums; i++){
        
            // Find the customer record ID of the customer on the line and store it
            let customerid = context.rec.getSublistValue({
                sublistId: 'line',
                fieldId: 'entity_display',
                line: i
            });

            // Then create a SS with the customer id as a criteria
            let customerSearch = search.create({
                type: "customer",
                filters:
                [
                   ["entityid","is",customerid]
                ],
                columns:
                [
                   search.createColumn({
                      name: "custentity2", 
                      label: "ADP ID"}),
                ],
             });
             // Run that ss and Store the ADP ID result into a vairable
            function RunSearch(searchVar) {
                return searchVar.run()
                };
            };
            RunSearch(customerSearch).each(function(result){
                var adpID = result.getValue({
                    name:'custentity2',
                });
                return false;
            });


              //log the JE line numbers as a test
            log.debug({
                title: 'CustomerADP ID',
                details: adpId
             });

             // Set the Line Employee ADP ID field value to the ADP ID vairable stored
            context.rec.setSublistValue({
                sublistId: "line",
                fieldId: "custcol_mhi_line_adp_id",
                line: i,
                value: adpId,
             });
             //End of the loop
            };

        
        return {
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
        };
    });`
```

Answer (score 3):

For SS2.1, you can do the following:

```
let { newRecord } = context; 

//Find how many lines are in this JE
let jeLineNums = newRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId:'line'
});
```

Alternatively, for SS2.0:

```
//Find how many lines are in this JE
var jeLineNums = context.newRecord.getLineCount({
    sublistId:'line'
});
```

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLineCount' of undefined [at
> Object.beforeSubmit (/SuiteScripts/Set Line Employee ADP
> ID.js:15:30)]"

The reason you're getting the error above is because you're trying to read an undefined property from `context`. The `context` object doesn't have a `rec` property. See more details here: [beforeSubmit(context)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4407992070.html)

Comment: Just to add on here: you can make a global var in SS2.0 named "rec" and then the first thing you do in the lifecycle functions is assign it to the record.... rec = context.newRecord